# Regex - remove regular expression

Tags: c#

I have use regex to get string in specific format. After many operation i want original string back.

Now i have used only one pattern , i am thinking of using more pattern  and i want to to identify the which pattern is applied on formatted string and revert it to original string.

Here is my piece of code ,

```
string formattedId=string.empty;

 /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
          this.InitializeComponent();
          this.idPattern = @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})";
          this.idReplacement = "$1-$2+$3";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the OnLostFocus event of the UIElement control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void UIElement_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          string formatted = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, this.idPattern , this.idReplacement );
          formattedId = formatted;
        }


public string GetOriginalString()
{
//// Now here i want to convert formatted string back to original string.
}
```

For example 123456789 string will formatted as 123-456+789 
after this i want to check which pattern is applied and get string back in original format

Comment: Why not just store the original string?

Comment: I dont want to store original string, i want to make that function more generic. So that it will identify pattern and gives original string.

will it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global string and put the textbox value in that string.
to view orignal string just use that global string:

```
   string formattedId=string.Empty;
   string OriginalStr=string.Empty; 
   public MainWindow()
   {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      this.idPattern = @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})";
      this.idReplacement = "$1-$2+$3";
   }

   private void UIElement_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       OriginalStr=Convert.ToString(textBox.Text);
       string formatted = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, this.idPattern , this.idReplacement );
       formattedId = formatted;
   }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: can we done without storing original value ?

i want to make it generic so that i can call it from different places.

Comment: I am afraid, that you won't get back originl if you wont't store it in temp and apply operations.